Fetch data through pinia store in nuxt3 project on ssr
I'm trying to create a Pinia store where I can collect and modify the data that is fetched in my application.
From my components, I want to just call the store in order to get the data needed, and then the store will take responsibility for caching and modifying the data.
vercelStore.ts:
    export const useVercelStore = defineStore('VercelStore', {
      state: () => ({
        stats: {} as any,
      }),
      actions: {
        async fetchStats(ssr: boolean = true) {
          // Dont fetch if data already exists with valid TTL
          if (this.stats && this.stats.ttl > new Date()) {
            return
          }
    
          const { data, error } = useCustomFetch('/status/vercel', {
            server: ssr,
          })
          if (data.value) {
            this.stats = {
              ttl: setTTL(5),
              data: data.value,
            }
          }
          if (error.value) {
            this.stats = {
              ttl: setTTL(2),
              data: null,
            }
          }
        },
      },
    })

My component:
    const vercelStore = useVercelStore()
    const { fetchStats } = vercelStore
    const vercelData = computed<UsageData | null>(() => vercelStore.stats.data)
    await fetchStats()

I currently have 2 issues. When fetching data withssr=true, it seems to work as expected because the data is loaded, but I get a mismatch:
rendered on server: <!---->  
- expected on client: Symbol(v-fgt) 

Second issue is that when ssr=false the request is correctly sent through the client but the store is never populated with the response of the request.
How can I structure my setup to make it work correctly?

So, do you want to have SSR or not? Having the issue on both sides is not useful here because you should pick one. As for the mismatch, start there and see what kind of code is running only on the client-side or the server. The error should help you narrow it down a bit more. Otherwise, you can always slap a client-only component in some places to narrow it down.

I want some requests te be handled during SSR and some requests on the client side. Ie. authentication I want handled on SSR but a slow data request I want to be handled in the client with corresponding skeletons. I dont want the SSR to wait for this response.
